# Linearly distorting the distribution of random numbers?

Tags: probability-distributions

I don't know any math notation, so I'll just write in plain english.  Though it isn't too important, I'm working in Javascript. What I want to know is basically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13457450/1597180) on stack overflow, though I think it's more appropriate for here, and it isn't getting much love there, anyway, so here goes.

Javascript has a facility for generating pseudorandom numbers between 1 and 0. However, I want to take the numbers that I get out of this and manipulate them in a way that will distort them with a bias toward numbers closer to 0 and against those closer to 1.  I thought and thought about this, but I couldn't figure out how to go about doing it, so I asked and someone on stack told me that I could simply take a random number, and **square it.**  This fulfills what I asked for, but I'd also like to know how, partly just to better my own understanding of the concept, to distribute them linearly.

I created a small script to visualize what different distortions look like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RTbrL/). To use it, you just need to open your javascript console in your browser. On Chrome, this can be done by pressing CTRL+Shift+J.

As you can see, raising the random number to a power produces a curve, like so:
[image]

Again, **how do you produce a line?**

Thanks